# Swift 3 add remove subview and its content dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiview

I am writing my first Swift app for quiz. Each question has random way to render on screen as below screenshot.

[image]

I am programming app without story board ie. programmatically. I want to create simple pagination flow for each question within single viewcontroller without using Collocationview, Tableview or navigation.

What I did so far?  I have simple viewcontroller with UIView() added as subview. I am adding question components dynamically. Now once user click on continue I wanted remove subview and add new subview with new question. I am able to remove subview but contents on subview seems to be still there as I can see its overwriting.

To get more clarification please view my code.

```
import UIKit

class QuizController: UIViewController {

let subView = UIView()
var currentQuestion:Int = 1;


let questions = ["This is question 1", "Hello to question 2", "Question 3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    setup_layout()
}

func setup_layout(){

    let closeBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 10, width: 200, height: 50))
    closeBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    closeBtn.setTitle("Close", for: .normal)
    closeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(close), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(closeBtn)
    //dynamic view
    create_subview()
}

func nextQuestion(){
    print("Show next")
    if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(currentQuestion) {
        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
        currentQuestion += 1;
        create_subview()
    } else {
        print("No!")
    }


}

func create_subview(){

    let heightOfView = view.frame.size.height
    let widthOfView = view.frame.size.width

    subView.tag = currentQuestion
    subView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2)
    subView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: self.view.frame.width, height: heightOfView - 60)
    self.view.addSubview(subView)

    let txtLabel1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 35, y: 120, width: widthOfView , height: 20))
    txtLabel1.text = questions[currentQuestion-1]
    txtLabel1.font = txtLabel1.font.withSize(12)
    subView.addSubview(txtLabel1)

    let nextBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 300, width: 200, height: 50))
    nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    nextBtn.setTitle("Continue", for: .normal)
    nextBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextQuestion), for: .touchUpInside)
    subView.addSubview(nextBtn)

}

func close(){
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

And this is what I see which I click continue.

[image]

NOTE: Initially thought using Collocation or Table view will be more appropriate as I can set to scroll horizontally for each question and fetch questions using REST API and place to each cell. But I want to present next screen to user only once then click on continue. I guess with collectionview user can move to next screen on swipe.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 - how that will help to remove label from the subview? let me update my post to show what i see when i click continue.

Comment: for view in self.view.subviews
            {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
            }

Use this code in create_subview() starting before adding anything.

Comment: Inventing the wheel is always a bad practise. This is why you should create  VCs inside the storyboard (or a nib file which will be a VC type and use its view) for every question with the unique UI.
Developing UI programmatically is a bad pracise and you should avoid it when developing iOS whenever it's possible. Leverage auotlayout as it should be. Your maintainability using a storyboard/nib will be super-agile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found the answer. I assumed removing subview will also remove all components on subview by itself ie. UILable and UIButton in my case.

I have to remove them separately.

```
for subview in self.subView.subviews {
       subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Now i can add tag to components and remove like this:

```
    for subview in self.subView.subviews {
        if (subview.tag == 1) {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you removing superviews and adding again and again?? Simply change UILabel.text :)

Answer (score 4):

Why are you removing superviews and adding again and again??
Simply change UILabel.text :)